# Can we change default names for database objects to upper case in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Whenever one creates a database object in PostgreSQL using unquoted identifiers, PostgreSQL folds them back to lowercase.

As an example the queries:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (A int);
```

```
CREATE TABLE My_Table (A int);
```

PostgreSQL will treat them the same as

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (a int);
```

I know if I want the object `MY_TABLE` and the column `A` to be named with upper case letters I need to use double quotes as in

```
CREATE TABLE "MY_TABLE" ("A" int);
```

My question is: can this behaviour be changed so that PostgreSQL defaults the names of the objects to uppercase (instead of lowercase) without the need of the quotes in every object and in every query? Is there any configuration in PostgreSQL that can be changed for that?

Ideally I would like PostgreSQL to convert a query such as

```
CREATE TABLE My_Table (A int);
```

to uppercase

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (A int);
```

This might be unusual but when working with multiple databases or performing a migration we might find some of them default objects to uppercase and some to lower case which might cause incompatibility issues.

Changing the default case is something that is possible in other databases such as Netezza. For instance, you can check it in here: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/changing%C2%A0default-case-all-database-objects

The closest to a solution I had so far is to create scripts to automatically use `ALTER TABLE` statements:

- https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/migrating-from-ms-sql-to-postgresql-uppercase-vs-lowercase/ or
- [Change table column names to upper case in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351743/change-table-column-names-to-upper-case-in-postgres).

However, my objective is that PostgreSQL looks for uppercase objects in the queries instead of lowercase ones. That is, after applying the solutions in the links, if I want to query the object I still would need the double quotes to do so. E.g. for my example after I create the uppercase object `MY_TABLE` the query

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE;
```

would still throw an error: `relation "my_table" does not exist`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Even though folding names to lower case violates the SQL standard, that behavior is deeply ingrained in PostgreSQL, and changing it would be a lot of work. In addition, we would not consider such a change, because that would cause a world of pain, because backward compatibility would be broken. And PostgreSQL will not accept any parameters and options that change how SQL behaves, because we have been burned by that before.

Sorry.